# how to search amadeus api one way flight. any idea about that

Tags: api, amadeus

Help me in the Amadeus API issue flight search section.
https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using GET : simply leave out the `returnDate` and only use `departureDate`.

If you are using POST: shouldn't be too much of an issue, since you specify every single leg of the journey on its own in `originDestinations` . So just enter your desired route there.